# Connect sql server to android through jdts

Tags: android, jdbc

i want to connect sql server to my android app.i tried below code but getting exception

> package com.facebook.android;
>
> import java.sql.Connection;
>
> import java.sql.DriverManager;
>
> import java.sql.ResultSet;
>
> import java.sql.Statement;
>
> import net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.*;
>
> import android.util.Log;
>
> public class ConnectSQL {
>
> public void testSQL (){
>
> ```
>       Log.d("Android"," MySQL Connect Example.");
>       Connection conn = null;
>         try {
>              String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
>              Class.forName(driver);
>             //test = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.class;
>              String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/Test";
>             String username = "";
>             String password = "";
>             conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,username,password);
>             Log.d("Connection","open");       
>             Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();    
>             ResultSet reset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");
>
>            //Print the data to the console    
>           while(reset.next()){
>             Log.d("Data:",reset.getString(1));
>            //Log.w("Data",reset.getString(2
>             //System.out.println("Result :" + reset.getInt("1")); 
>           }
>          conn.close();
>
>       } catch (Exception e)       
>          { 
>              Log.d("Error connection","" +
>            e.getMessage());
>           }
> ```
>
> }
>   }

I am getting this exception

> Error connection(1833): net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

Comment: same error to me also .I have used 1.2.5.jar file as library file and also tried with 1.2.7 and 1.3.0 versions but no success...

Answer (score 0):

**Right click on your project ==? properties ==> order and export ==> check the jtds**
and clean your project and rebuild your apk.
i think its going to work.